# JMeter Thread User Limit - execute 5000 threads concurrently

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I tried to test how many limits of VUs that my pc can handle. So far i tried to run with 5000 VUs with GUI mode, its working fine so wondering if this is really the correct way to do it. Here's my laptop specification:

16GB DDR4, 512GB SSD, i5 7th gen

For now I already test with 6 HTTP requests, thread group information as below:

[image]

[image]

Can anyone verify whether im doing correct way to test the limit? And why does when the test is running, the number of user run at top right is still 47? But at the end of the test, it really shows that it ends with 5000 VUs in the summary report listener (Please refer Jmeter logs in the first screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

1. You have only 1 loop and 120 seconds ramp-up in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) so JMeter starts 41 users each second. Once started user starts executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down and when the last sampler is done the thread is being shut down.

   So you're running into the situation when some threads have already finished their job and ended and some haven't been yet started. If you want to reach 5000 users then you need to tick `Infinite` next to Loop Count and specify `Thread Lifetime` to be greater than your ramp-up time.

   More information: [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected)
2. According to [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean)  you should:

   - Run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
   - Disable or delete all the [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html)  as they don't add any value, just consume the resources

   Once your non-GUI test execution is finished you can either open the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) using a Listener of your choice or [generate HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) out of it and analyze the results

Comment: Thank you sir. I tried to set the loop count to infinite. but after it reach the 5000 users, the test still running right? then is it normal to have so much errors on HTTP requests after that?

Comment: The test will be running for the **Duration (seconds)** specified in the Thread Group. w.r.t. the number of errors - it's a different story, most probably your application gets overloaded. look into [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime) and [Response Codes per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseCodesPerSecond) to see where the problems start, it's also a good idea to use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) to see if there is a lack of resources