# Limit of 2000 concurrent threads between JMeter and Spring Boot web server

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency, jmeter, performance-testing

I am observing a strange behaviour between JMeter and a simple Spring Boot web server, both running on my local machine.

I run a simple web service call in many threads concurrently. When I set JMeter to run 2000 threads, everything works OK. When I set it to 2001, most requests fail.

**What kind of a magic number is 2000?** Which settings causes this limit?

Configuration:

- Windows 11
- Java 21
- Spring Boot 3.2.0-RC1 (but the same behaviour with 3.1.5)
- Apache JMeter 5.6.2
- 16 cores CPU
- 64 GB memory

I have found a similar sounding question [JMeter Thread User Limit - execute 5000 threads concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68539578/2886891) but it does not seem to cover the same problem.

#### Spring Boot code:

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {
    @GetMapping
    public String getPerson() {
        return "John";
    }
}
```

#### application.properties:

```
server.port=9001
server.tomcat.threads.max=10000
server.tomcat.max-connections=10000
server.tomcat.accept-count=10000
```

#### Spring Boot start log:

```
MyApplication                            : Starting MyApplication using Java 21 with PID 71328
MyApplication                            : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 9001 (http)
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.15]
o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 671 ms
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 9001 (http) with context path ''
MyApplication                            : Started MyApplication in 1.302 seconds (process running for 1.812)
o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
```

### JMeter request configuration:

[image]

#### JMeter result for 2000 concurrent threads:

[image]

#### JMeter result for 2001 concurrent threads:

[image]

JMeter shows each error as `HttpHostConnectException` and it seems like the call doesn't reach the Spring Boot application at all:

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9001 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:409)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:940)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:651)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1311)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1300)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:589)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:583)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:751)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a networking configuration problem of your operating system, things you could try to do are:

1. [Increase dynamic port range for TCP/IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/tcp-ip-port-exhaustion-troubleshooting#default-dynamic-port-range-for-tcpip)
2. [Decrease TcpTimedWaitDelay](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.5.x?topic=system-recycling-tcp-connections-microsoft-windows-operating%20%203.%20Increase%20the%20number%20of%20TCP%20connections:)
3. [Increase the number of TCP connections](https:////www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.5.x?topic=itspmwos-increasing-maximum-number-tcp-connections-microsoft-windows-operating-system)

Few other things to consider:

- In general I don't think it's "2000" which is the magic number, you can try adding [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) listener to see how many maximum users were online, I think it's less than 2000.
- Sending 2000 requests is not something you should be normally doing, I would rather [increase the load gradually](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period), i.e. for a couple of minutes and leave 2000 users up and running for another couple of minutes, this way you will be able to correlate the increasing load with increasing response time or errors start occurring.
- Having load generator and the system under test on the same machines is also not something you should be normally doing because it's unlikely you will get good/valid results as both JMeter and Spring Boot will be [struggling for the operating system resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) and won't perform good enough. In general you should run tests either against production environment or its exact replica, you cannot extrapolate test results from a scaled-down environment onto larger one because there are too many variables to consider.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also suspect *some* setting in my operating system. However it is really just the +1 which makes the difference between 2000 and 2001, I tried it many many times. And I am aware that this is not an ideal test setup, that the JMeter and the testing application should run on different machines. Still the setup is good enough for local experimenting :) Only the limit of the exactly and always nice round 2000 what makes me unhappy.

Comment: I tried the parameters. `netsh int ipv4 show dynamicport tcp` shows `Number of Ports: 64511`. And `TcpNumConnections` is not present in my Registry, according to https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.2.0?topic=services-verifying-tcpip-parameter-settings-windows-servers "If this parameter is not defined, the default value of 6,777,214 TCP connections is used." So I cannot see those parameters as limit.

Comment: Yes, the maximum threads over time (when I set the granularity to 1 ms) was something slightly over 1200, so it indeed *is* below 2000. Even more I do not understand the magic number 2001.